# Pass parameter to constructor - NativeLookup.create

Tags: codenameone

How can I pass parameter to constructor of Native code in Codename one?

I could only see NativeLookup.create method which takes no parameter. The requirement is to create native object based on parameter (like port number or url).

```
NativeCode nativeCode = (NativeCode) NativeLookup.create(NativeCode.class);
```

It would be even great if there is any way to get instance from a factory method which takes parameter. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't and you don't need to!

The native interface is a simple interface. If you have an object that needs a constructor argument just create it within the native object methods. Keep in mind that passing an argument to a constructor might work well for Android but when you want to do the same thing in iOS's Objective-C etc. this might not make sense.